# Spring Boot Request Scoped Beans Autowired not Populated

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm new to Spring Boot, I only like to use its dependency injection, not all its opinionated frameworks but some. I know there are other alternatives for this functionality, but I would like to learn more Spring.

I am trying to have a request scoped bean and populate it with regular dependency injection. My plan is to have some User object that I can populate hold some custom business details that is easy to access that makes code clean.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class MyBean {
  @Autowired
  lateinit var req: HttpServletRequest

  @Autowired
  lateinit var env: Environment

  @PostConstruct
  fun pc() {
    println("I am constructed $this, $req, $env")
  }

  var a = 3
}


@RestController
class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/api/xyz")
    fun login(m: MyBean): Int {
        println("new bean m")
        return m.a
    }
}
```

Every time I hit that endpoint, I see new objects are instantiated. However the inner dependencies are not autowired, they are always null. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to write a filter? But how would I know how to find all the endpoints that needs that bean to be initialized? If, I remove the request scope the variables are initialized.

Comment: I'm curious to know which frameworks are not opinionated.

Comment: Who said others weren't opinionated?

Comment: You said you didn't like all of Spring's opinionated frameworks.  My point is that all frameworks are opinionated to some degree.  Hence, my remark.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion and discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RestControllers` are beans like `Components` or `Services`. So in all of these you should deal with injected dependencies the same way.

Coming to the example you were adding, beans should not be parameters of actual endpoint mappings. Asking for request specific information like headers, path variables or the payload body are candidates for endpoint mapping method arguments.

For a bean instance of your class `MyBean` you should rather use a member variable injected directly or via the constructor of your `MyController` (where constructor based injection is the recommended approach).

Don't be confused when injecting your `MyBean` which is `RequestScoped` in the constructor of `MyController`: this is totally intended and works. Spring actually injects a proxy instance that will resolve to the request specific instance once your request is reaching the controller invocation.

Comment: so the proxy deals with concurrency issues? Since the RestController will be application scoped, singleton, the other bean will be Request Scoped, but the accessed object in each request will be different via proxy? The thing is not all methods would need those objects and I did not want them to be controller-global. 

I would normally inject POJOs in the mapping, but they would need some other services to fill them. I think what I am looking for is handler or interceptor or filter, but I honestly cannot search Google good enough to find them. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, Spring deals with giving your http-thread execution the correct actual instance dedicated to your request through the proxy that is injected into a broader-scoped bean.

A good start for reading about filters in Spring would be: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter